# Проблемы с декларации переменных

Tags: c++

Проблема заключается в то, что этот участок кода работает нормально, но из-за него проблемы.

```
if (mode == 1)
{
    Animal main_object;
}
else if (mode == 2)
{
    Human main_object;
}
else
{
    Cat main_object;
}

std::string name_object;
std::cin >> name_object;
main_object.set_name(name_object);
```

т.е. когда я обращаюсь к `main_object` я получаю это :

```
main.cpp:185:2: ошибка: нет декларации «main_object» в этой области видимости
main_object.get_object()->set_name(name_object);
```

как это обойти это или какие костыли использовать?

p.s. h фаил классов

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <string>

class Animal
{
  public:
          Animal();
          Animal(std::string name_arg, int year_arg);
          ~Animal();

  protected: std::string name;
  public:
          std::string get_name();
          void set_name(std::string name_arg);

  protected: int year;
  public:
          virtual int get_year();
          virtual void set_year(int year_arg);

          virtual void show();
          virtual void say_something();
};


class Human : public Animal
{
  public:
          Human();
          Human(std::string name_arg, int year_arg);
          Human(const Human& object);
          ~Human();

          int get_year();
          void set_year(int year_arg);

          void show();
          void say_something();
};


class Cat : public Animal
{
  public:
          Cat();
          Cat(std::string name_arg, int year_arg);
          Cat(const Cat& object);
          ~Cat();

          int get_year();
          void set_year(int year_arg);

          void show();
          void say_something();
};

#endif
```

Comment: В этом коде три разных `main_object`, но нет обращений ни к одному

Comment: @VTT дело не в том что нет кода, а в том что я не могу до него достучаться. я пытюсь обраться к методу, а в итогу получаю эту ошибку. там имена методов одинаковые т.к. наследуются

Comment: "я пытюсь обраться к методу" - нет, не пытаетесь

Comment: В теле конструкции обьявляете обьект, а потом хотите использовать?  Конечно не получится

Comment: @VTT обновил главную страницу

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так вот я и спрашиваю как это можно сделать на подобии

Comment: Теперь для полноты картины еще добавьте описания этих классов. Если все три класса имеют общего полиморфного предка, то можно использовать указатель на этого предка, выделяя объекты динамически, иначе пилить что-то типа variant.

Comment: @VTT я добавил h фаил без фаилов реализации. по названиям я думаю вы поймёте.

Comment: @VTT А можете развить тему про variant, т.к. я пытался сделать класс type_class но както всё рано не получалость. Если нужно могу дать этот нерабочий код

Comment: `std::variant` не нужен, ведь полиморфный (т.е. с виртуальными функциями) предок есть. Нужно что-то типа `Animal *main_object; if (mode == 1) {main_object = new Animal;} else if (mode == 2) {main_object = new Human;} ...`. (В идеале вообще `std::unique_ptr` вместо обычного указателя.)

Comment: Делайте `virtual ~Animal();`, объявляйте переменную `::std::unique_ptr<Animal> p_animal{};`, а потом динамически создавайте экземпляр нужного класса: `p_animal = ::std::make_unique<Cat>();`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а виртуальные функции все переопределятся. т.е. Конструктор класса Cat будет работать как полагается? И да спасибо, что вспомнили про умные указатели, но для меня это перебор.

Comment: @VTT извините но умные уразатели будут перебор. т.к. само студентческое задание подразумевает знакомства с классом и самому мне эту тему сложно понять

Comment: Не хочет работать: https://ideone.com/Sso4jT. Хотя по идее вроде бы должно: https://ideone.com/aeiv2x

Comment: @ЕвгенийКаратаев Да, все будет нормально. Но действительно нужно сделать деструктор виртуальным и не забыть потом вызвать `delete`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat про `delete` я понял, а вот почему деструктор нужно делать виртуальный не могу догаться почему. И у какого класса/ов

Comment: Это нужно тогда, когда вы удаляете объект через указатель не на его настоящий тип, а на родителя. В комментариях долго объяснять, проще загуглить. *"И у какого класса/ов"* У родителя. Потомки получат виртуальный деструктор автоматически.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо большое за ответ. жалко, что не вы сделали ответ, но вы очень сильно помогли. И да, я знаю что такое деструктор. последние 2 предложения полностью покрыли вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мы имеем дело с иерархией, то можем легко обеспечить полиморфизм времени выполнения:

```
 class Animal {
    //...
    public:
    virtual void set_name(const std::string& s){ ...}

}; 
//...
```

Тогда легко сделать то, что вы задумали:

```
//...
Animal a; Human h; Cat c;
Animal* p;   
if (mode == 1)
{
    p = &a;
}
else if (mode == 2)
{
   p = &h;
}
else
{
     p = &c;
}
Animal& main_object = *p;
std::string name_object;
std::cin >> name_object;
main_object.set_name(name_object);
```

Comment: Эм.. Ты создаёшь 3 объекта вместо одного.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Да, но это всего лишь демонстрация, а не полный код, который можно написать совершенно иначе

Comment: Ну я как-то не представляю, как его изменить, чтобы создавался только нужный объект. Подозреваю, то автор вопроса - тоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему же: первый способ, это создание обьекта в динамической памяти...

Comment: С `new` понятно. А без него?

Comment: @Qwertiy, без него  mode может быть  constexpr,  и  написать шаблон класса с соответствующими специализациями

Comment: Можно управлять временем жизни с помощью placement new в локальном буфере. Как вариант, можно использовать свою класс-обертку с отсроченным созданием объекта. Также можно использовать variant

Comment: @Croessmah,  конечно, но почему то мне показалось, что автору вопроса не это интересовало, а  единственное имя(не единственный обьект)

Comment: @Croessmah,     И, как  выяснилось, у него даже нет инфы об умных указательях, а значит  с variant   ом тоже без варианта...